# Ubuntu 16.04 wpa_supplicant - AndroidAP showing connected but browser not working

Tags: networking

I have been trying to connect to WPA2 wifi from the command line. Ive read all the tutorials I can find and followed along. Most of them seem to say similar stuff.  Here is the state of my wpa_supplicant config file.

```
# reading passphrase from stdin
network={
        ssid="AndroidAP"
        psk="xxxxxx"
        psk=b87678f912341488b23729cca223c53507fd0c33620098a3187aab7ca59de057
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=RSN WPA
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

Then after doing the usual stuff, I get to this point.

```
root@willow-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/home/willow# /sbin/iw wlo1 link
Connected to ac:af:b9:37:d6:3e (on wlo1)
    SSID: AndroidAP
    freq: 2412
    RX: 439571 bytes (3739 packets)
    TX: 9744 bytes (51 packets)
    signal: -29 dBm
    tx bitrate: 13.0 MBit/s MCS 1

    bss flags:  short-slot-time
    dtim period:    2
    beacon int: 100

root@willow-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/home/willow# sudo dhclient wlo1
root@willow-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/home/willow# sudo dhclient wlo1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists

root@willow-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/home/willow# ip link show wlo1 
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:a9:82:4c:8c:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

root@willow-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/home/willow# ip addr show wlo1  
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:a9:82:4c:8c:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.175/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global wlo1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8ea9:82ff:fe4c:8c5a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Problem is the browser doesn't work. The only thing I haven't tried, that I have read is to purge network manager off the system.  I don't want to do this, because if I cant get the command lines to work, how can I get back on line?           Any thoughts?  Thanks.

///////////Edit1///////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is the outcome of my attempted ping

```
root@willow-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/home/willow# ping -c 10 linuxfoundation.com
ping: unknown host linuxfoundation.com
root@willow-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/home/willow#
```

Also after using the commands

```
sudo dhclient -r wlo1
sudo ifconfig wlo1 down
```

I still had to reboot the machine to get network manager to work,

Comment: Just the browser doesn't work? So you can ping addresses?

Comment: Thanks,   I just tried a ping and will edit my question with the outcome.

Comment: Is there a file that I can comment out a line or two, that will disable netwok manager at boot time?

Comment: you can disable network manager at boot by disabling the service `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service`. Also try pinging an IP instead of a domain name to rule out a DNS issue. `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: @ hamiheim   Thanks for the advice.  I tried it with network manager disabled and it worked.  Always good to have a backup plan for getting on line, cheers